# How to navigate directly into a webpage bypassing keycloak login page using powershell script?

Tags: powershell, keycloak, invoke-webrequest

I'm trying to navigate directly into my item page (by provided item ID). I can generate access token using client id and client secret. But even though I pass it through header, it responds with the keycloak login page.

My sample PowerShell script is as below.

```
$TokenEndpoint = "$server_location/auth/realms/$key_cloak_client/protocol/openid-connect/token"
$itemID = 100

$OauthTokensClient = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $TokenEndpoint -Method POST -Body @{
   grant_type   = 'client_credentials'
   client_id    = <Client_ID>
   client_secret = <Client_Secret>
   scope        = 'openid profile'
}

$AccessTokenClient = $OauthTokensClient.access_token
$HeaderClient = @{"Accept" = "application/json" ; "authorization" = "Bearer $AccessTokenClient"}

$Result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$server_location/item/?item_id=$itemID" -Header $HeaderClient
"$Result"
```

`$Result` prints contents on keycloak login page instead of my item page content.
Please help or shed some lite on correct path to archive this task.

Comment: You are not getting to the route (URI).  Without debugging the server it is impossible to tell why this is happening.  Normally when a HTTP connection completes you will get a 200 OK in the body of the response.  Or get a 400/500 error with no body.  Because you are getting the login page (which is the body) it implies you got a 200 OK.  It looks like on your server you have a [Authorize] that is not working.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Is the url specifically an api endpoint, or is it an end-user webpage designed to be shown in a browser? Some *websites* set additional session state (e.g. a session id cookie) as well as the auth token when you log in, so you might need additional details in your request to avoid triggering the login redirect. Try capturing the manual login process in a MITM proxy - e.g Fiddler, or Chrome Dev Tools and try to reproduce the login and  “item page” requests as they appear there. The specific details vary by site so you might need to experiment to find the exact magic headers / cookies needed…

Comment: @mclayton thanks for the tips. And yes. it is an end-user webpage (not api endpoint). For api endpoints it works fine and goes through keycloak autherisation layer. I will try as you mentioned.